# Python and PAMIE

Tags: python

I am having trouble navigaing a website with PAMIE. I want to invidually use it to open IE, then put in my username and password on a website. First I am trying o just navigate a site. This is what I have so Far....

```
from PAM30 import PAMIE

ie = PAMIE.PAMIE() 
website = "http://www.python.org" 
ie.navigate(website) 
ie.textBoxSet('q', 'pamie') 
ie.buttonClick('submit')
```

So this "should" open python.org and in search put Pame and submit. The error I am getting is....

```
AttributeError: type object 'PAMIE' has no attribute 'PAMIE'
```

I know this is probably something stupid, but I can't figure it out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't use PAMIE, but [it seems](http://www.whichtestingtool.com/reviews/13-pamie.html) you need to write `ie = PAMIE()`, not `ie = PAMIE.PAMIE()` because PAM30.PAMIE is a class itself.

Comment: great that work.. not it won't populate pamie in the search field I get

Comment: sorry I get...AttributeError: 'PAMIE' object has no attribute 'textBoxSet'  ,,

Comment: The method is calling setTextBox.

Comment: do you know where i can get a list of Pamie attributes cause my clickbutton isn't working either

Comment: got it neverminf, but a list would sure help a newbie like me

Comment: Use Python's built-in function called [help](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#help): `help(ie)`